# How to remove a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a one file upload button.And i write a jquery validation in upload button.If i don't choose any image error message is displayed but if i click a error message it do file upload functionality?

This is my input type file format:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile1" id="userfile1" class="span5" ></input>
```

This is my jquery validation:

```
$(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Must Select Image To Upload"
        }
    });
```

add is button name. if i click "Must Select Image To Upload" this message it do file upload functionality.

How to i remove this link.

Kindly give a solution...

Comment: Your question is not clear to us !!!

Comment: @Abhishek how is that relevant?

Comment: i does not select any image so error message is displayed.if i click a  require message it to file upload functionality. how to remove it.

Comment: oops sorry,my answer didnt pasted at all

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: file upload button and require message have a same id.dynamically created for id.how to remove for id in dynamically

Answer (score 2):

I think you asking about, when user click on the file upload element, hide the error message.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="userfile1" id="userfile1" class="span5" ></input>
<div id="errorDiv">Must Select Image To Upload</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#userfile1").focus(function () {    
        $('#errorDiv').fadeOut(2000);    //replace '#errorDiv' to your error message id.
});
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/S4Snn/)**</kbd>

**UPDATE :** Check if the element value is empty or not in `#add` button `click()` function. If the value is empty then show the `#errorDiv`. Write your hiding error div function in on `focus` of `input` element.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="userfile1" id="userfile1" class="span5"></input>
<div id="errorDiv">Must Select Image To Upload</div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="ADD" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#errorDiv').hide();
$('#add').click(function () {
    if ($("#userfile1").val() === '') $('#errorDiv').fadeIn(1000);
});
$("#userfile1").focus(function () {
    $('#errorDiv').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S4Snn/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: if i click a add button it check validation

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div id="errorDiv"></div>
  <input type="file" name="userfile1" id="userfile1" class="span5" ></input>

   $('.span5').each(function() {

   if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)
   {
     $("#errorDiv").html("Must Select Image To Upload ");
   }
});
```